# Como fazer o Firebase Cloud Messaging enviar uma mensagem para um usuário em especifico?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou tentando fazer o Firebase Cloud Messaging enviar uma mensagem para um usuário em especifico mais não estou conseguindo...
Primeiro eu estou registrando o aparelho e salvando o id no meu servidor:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                return;
            }

            // Pega o ID token
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();
            // depois envia para o servidor
            saveToken(token);


        }
    });
```

Então eu tento enviar a minha mensagem pelo back-end para:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Com o id que foi cadastrado no banco de dados

Como neste tutorial de exemplo:

http://ricardolecheta.com.br/?p=894

Answer (score 0):

> Primeiro verifique se o token esta salvando no seu servidor,
>   Teste no postman com o token que vc pegar no Android e veja se da success, por que se vc não colocou o google-services.json corretamente não gera o token certo

Não esquece de incluir no manifest.xml do service do push

```
  <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

O envio para um usuário especifico é feito pelo console do firebase inserindo o token firebase do dispositivo ou configurando um servidor para enviar para aquele token especifico.

Clique [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message?hl=pt-br%22)